# Javascript: go to error page when any variable is undefined or null

Tags: javascript, variables, null, undefined

I want to redirect to error page in the application , when any of the variable in the whole app is undefined or null.

Instead of crashing app, I want to redirect to error page.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: Would you please provide your code and trials?

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code in *Try catch* statement

```
try{
    var a = undefined;
    var b = a.length;
} catch(ex) { 
    console.log(ex);
    //redirect to your error page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, having a variable with a value of `undefined` or `null` is not necessarily an error. If in your case you consider it to be an error, you have two options in my opinion:

### Use TypeScript and `try-catch` block

TypeScript does all the type-checking for you, and if you were careful with defining all the types correctly, an exception should be thrown when any of them becomes `null` or `undefined`, where you can then catch it inside a `try-catch` and redirect the user to the error page.

```
try {
  ...
} catch (Exception ex) {
  window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/error";
}
```

### Continuously check for values

If you are not into using TypeScript, you can do the checking manually, either every time interval:

```
setInterval(checkAllValues(), 1000)
```

or upon certain operations that you suspect it might yield `null` or `undefined`.

```
let myValue = doSomeOperations();
if (myValue === undefined || myValue === null) {
  window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/error";
}
```

This solution might not very practical, as it requires you to know all the variables and might need to keep a centralised store for keeping them, but it should work fine for simple projects.